# Can I use 印象 to talk about something the subject does not have personal experience with, but has an opinion about?

Tags: words

I'm sorry for the weird title. English is not my first language and I'm not sure how to put it...
I wanted to say something among the lines "How Americans imagine Japan to be/What is Japan like, according to Americans" - the nuance being that I'm talking about Americans who have never been to Japan. I was thinking of using 印象, but I think 印象 is more about looking at something and getting an impression of what is it like, so it might not really be the best choice of words. Is there a nice, simple way of stating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want to simply say "an image of Japan, you can use イメージ:

> 日本のイメージ
>   日本に対するイメージ

It doesn't determine if someone had or had not direct experience with Japan. The image might change when getting more exposure.

To emphasize imaginative aspect you might decide for: "Japan as imagined by Americans"

> アメリカ人が想像する日本
>   アメリカ人の想像する日本